# Is there a library in Objective-C to edit id3 tags in mp3 files?

Tags: objective-c, id3-tag

I need to generate test data and would like to do it with Objective-C in Xcode. So far I have not found an id3 tag library for Objective-C that writes data. I have found a few libraries which can read the data.

Any tips on Open Source projects which do this? Should I consider a different programming language?

Comment: Maybe you'd be interested `AVFoundation.framework`

Comment: Did you get any further here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

AudioFileSetProperty() //  kAudioFilePropertyID3Tag
```

have fun!

Comment: how do you use AudioFileSetProperty though? i tried this http://pastie.org/4868001 just as a test to see if the title of the song would change to max, it didnt though. i use a cfdictionary because in another part of code, thats how its read so i assume to save it, i also use that. i tried nsdictionary, but that didnt work ether

Answer (score 1):

If you're having trouble finding an Objective C based library, then I would agree that it would be worth considering increasing your options to include plain C based libraries. With Objective C being fully C compliant, interfacing with C based libraries is very natural.

Comment: I will expand my search. Thanks for the suggestion.